# React Router Dom doesn't redirect to specified path on entering of wrong path after handling that. How do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How do I handle wrong routes like `localhost:4800/sajkfa` to redirect to the not found component `<Page404 />`

As it stands, the dashboard layout renders when I enter a wrong path. The `<DashboardLayout></DashboardLayout/>` wrap the private routes of the App and contain the navigation for the protected routes.

Here is my Dashbaord Layout:

```
<div className="dashboard">
  <DashboardSidebar showSidebar={isVisible} closeSidebar={closeSidebar}/>
  <div className="dashboard__body">
    <DashboardHeader 
      title={title} 
      openSidebar={openSidebar}
    />
    <main className="dashboard__main">
      <div className="dashboard__container">
        {children}
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `{children}` renders the current route component.

Here is my App Component that houses all the routes. The last code is meant to route to `<Page404 />` if the path doesn't match any component mapped to it.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />

    
     <DashboardLayout title={title}>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/a" component={A}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/b" component={B}/>

     </DashboardLayout>

    <Route path="*" component={Page404} />
 </Switch>
```

Here is the code that handles the private routes:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, title, ...rest }) => {
  const { loading, data } = useSelector((state) => state.login)
  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    data?.data?.token && !loading
      ? <Component {...props} title={title}/>
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
    )} 
  />
}
```

The code above routes the user to the Login Component if the user doesn't have an auth token on entering a valid path.

I expect the line of code below in my `<App />` below to route to `<Page404 />` by default if user enters wrong route but it stays on the wrong route and displays my empty `<DashboardLayout />` with no content which is never supposed to be displayed to the user except when logged in. Here is the line:

```
<Route path="*" component={Page404} />
```

How do I get it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the utility of `DashboardLayout`, please ?

Comment: @Nokwiw I used `DashboardLayout` to wrap my application private routes. It contains the navbar and sidebar

Comment: Try removing `path="*"` from `<Route path="*" component={Page404} />` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Switch />` should have `<Route />` as direct children and [does not check if you pass other types of children](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/4762).

If you pass `<DashboardLayout>` as a child, that route is always matched => `<DashboardLayout />` is rendered => `<Route path="*" component={Page404} />` is not rendered.

The quickest fix is to move the `<DashboardLayout />` inside the `<PrivateRoute />`

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, title, ...rest }) => {
    const { loading, data } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) =>
                data?.data?.token && !loading ? (
                    <DashboardLayout title={title}>
                        <Component {...props} title={title} />
                    </DashboardLayout>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                )
            }
        />;
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try below changes in your authenticated route

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, title, ...rest }) => {
  const { loading, data } = useSelector((state) => state.login)
  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    data?.data?.token && !loading
      ? <Component {...props} title={title}/>
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
    )} 
  />
}
export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

and wrap your route file inside

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />

    
     <DashboardLayout title={title}>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/a" component={A}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/b" component={B}/>

     </DashboardLayout>

    <Route component={Page404} />
 </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. This is my App.js. I have a login and other website routes under '/web' and app structure(console) under '/console'. I manage the wrong URL here(for non-authenticated users) and again on the ROUTES component of the console layout(for the authenticated users, manually putting the wrong URL, check below my layout and routes component). I consider this as the first check for non-authenticated users. So my console layout is not visible unless authenticated.

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>    
          <Route
            path="/console"
            render={() => (
              <ConsoleFinalLayout />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/web"
            render={() => (
              <LandingPage>
                <BaseRouter />
              </LandingPage>
            )}
          />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    ) 
  }
```

This is my App Console Main Component, I check isAuthenticated User here, and redirect to the login page.

```
ConsoleFinalLayout = 

    render() {
        return this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
              <ConsoleComponent />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/web/login" }} />
        );
      }


ConsoleComponent = 

    render() {
        return(
            <Layout>
              <Routes/>
            </Layout> 
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this method, you render the common layout component again on every route render. Let's say you have a Header and Footer component in all those pages or Layout, you render them again every time you change your route.

Comment: No, header and footer are on my layout component., which is rendered once, The return statement of my LAYOUT component includes "this.props.children" along with common layout things(header and footer).  I set this.props.children = ROUTES component which includes different links.  My menu is also defined in the LAYOUT component. So on the menu click the route changes and accordingly the component.  I think my LAYOUT component is rendered only once and based on menu(routes) child component changes.

Comment: More specifically  "localhost:3000/console" renders my ConsoleFinalLayout component and all child components of LAYOUT or component according to routes  renders at "localhost:3000/console/childComponent"

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    
     <DashboardLayout title={title}>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/a" component={A}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/b" component={B}/>

     </DashboardLayout>

    <Route path="/not-found" component={Page404} />
    <Redirect to="/not-found" />
 </Switch>
```

in the `PrivateRoute`, I prefere use this code :

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, title, ...rest }) => {
  const { loading, data } = useSelector((state) => state.login)
  return (data?.data?.token && !loading ?
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (<Component {...props} title ={title}/>
      : <Redirect to='/login' />)
    )} 
  />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but it didn't work. When logged out, your code treats invalid paths as valid ones and redirects them to the Login Page. It should only redirect valid paths to the Login Page when not logged in. It should redirect invalid path to the 404 page. When logged in, your code renders the dashboard which I want hidden and doesn't render the 404 page at all.

Comment: Your welcome, When logged out, your code treats invalid paths as valid ones and redirects them to the Login Page ==> that means it's work because when logget out you schould redirect your user to the Login page whitout consider wath path he is enter.

When logged in, your code renders the dashboard which I want hidden and doesn't render the 404 page at all. ==< can you show me your `DashboardLayout` please ?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the `DashboardLayout` . Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

The path it should start from the more specific to the more general.
try to put the route `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>` the last one.
when you use `Switch` no need to use `exact` keyword. And you need to add a path for the error page after that the last one you can add redirect

try this instead

```
<Switch>
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
 <DashboardLayout title={title}>
   <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home}/>
   <PrivateRoute path="/a" component={A}/>
   <PrivateRoute path="/b" component={B}/>
   <Route path="/not-found" component={Page404} />
   <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home}/>
 </DashboardLayout>    
 <Redirect to="/not-found" />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you but won't this render the dashboard layout with the 404 page. I do not want the dashboard layout(Header and Sidebar) rendered with the 404 page.

Comment: Ok I see try to put this `<PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home}/>` just before the redirect. because the rules is put the url from the more specific to the more general.
For exmple if you have route with params you start by those path then you finish by `/`

Answer (score 0):

To redirect user to `no match` route we need to keep track of valid routes and check if user requested valid route if not then we render `no match` route if yes then we check if the user is requesting logged in route we validate if he/she logged in if not redirect it to login route if yes render the requested route.

```js
const routes = {
  '/': Home,
  '/a': A,
  '/b': B
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, title, ...rest }) => {
  const { loading, data } = useSelector((state) => state.login)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (routes[props.location.pathname]) {
          if (data?.data?.token && !loading) {
            return (
              <DashboardLayout title={title}>
                <Component {...props} title={title} />
              </DashboardLayout>
            );
          }
          return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

In the login route I have tested if the user is logged in if yes then redirect him to the home route or else login page is rendered.

One problem is you are using `DashBoardLayout` inside `Switch` which should not be the case as it would stop the flow of moving from one routes to another and would never reach `no match` route, because `Switch` component would stop moving to next route as soon has something is returned from the route component even though it is not returned from the route component but something is there which can be returned.

```js
<Switch>
   {Object.keys(routes).map((route, idx) => (
     <PrivateRoute
       key={idx}
       exact
       path={route}
       component={routes[route]}
     />
   ))}

   <Route
     exact
     path="/login"
     component={() => {
       if (data?.data?.token) {
         return <Redirect to="/" />;
       }
       return <div>login</div>;
     }}
   />
   <Route path="*" component={() => <div>Page404</div>} />
</Switch>
```

Here sample working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8hkfbd)

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to default to a `404 Page`:**

- For paths that *do not exist in your routes*,
  simply use `Route without a path` like this:

  ```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />

     <DashboardLayout title={title}>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/a" component={A}/>

       <PrivateRoute exact path="/b" component={B}/>

      </DashboardLayout>

    <Route component={Page404} />
  </Switch>
  ```